# Wowza Using GSON stops the flow but doesn't throw any exception

Tags: java, json, gson, wowza

I'm using the latest Wowza Streaming Engine and my goal is to create a webapp that provides the dynamic overlays that I want to be injected into the incoming frames. Like Wirecast. So I've made a client that enables the user to add a dynamic overlays and bypass the frames uploaded by the encoder. I used JSON to pass the overlays' specs (image path, width, etc.) from the client and I'm trying to convert it to a Java Object using GSON. But my problem is once I initialize the GSON object, the program flow stops at that certain point. What's more weird is that it doesn't throw any exception. I looked at the logs, no errors. What's happening? Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to debug the code [based on this video](http://wowzatoolbox.com/debugging-wowza-module). I have written a [dynamic overlay module](https://wowzatoolbox.com/clamp), also used GSON and had no problems. So it's surely feasible.

Comment: I watched the video. Where should I insert the line in Linux (startup.sh) or does it differ from that of the startup.bat?

Comment: Had it debugging. It lead me to a warning that AbstractIoFilterChain.class was not found inside the wms-core.jar. This warning appears when I step over the Gson object initialization.

Comment: `AbstractIoFilterChain.class` should be in `wms-core.jar`, at least it is in my Wowza 4.0.3 installation. This comes with the Apache Mina library that is bundled inside this jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to close this. Anyways, the answer lies on the GSON jar file not existing in the Wowza lib directory ([wowza-install-dir]/lib). Thanks to jabal.